# C++ What happens to a Template Metaprogram's O notation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, template-meta-programming

Suppose that I will be able to implement a template metaprogram that will "search for a duplicate element in an array or any container" or say a Fibonacci template metaprogram. We know that the best case performance for this is O(N^2) and O(2^N) for the Fibonacci. What happens to the time complexity, since templates are evaluated/loaded on compile time? Would it become O(1) or will it depend on the number of elements of a container O(N)?

Comment: Show some example code. Also, what do you think would happen and why?

Comment: The complexity stays the same, but you feel the pain at compile time and not at run time (if you do all the work at compile time, you'll get a run time constant). But does this really matter? Can you really get an interesting input at compile time, large enough for the complexity to make a difference?

Comment: It does not really matter. I just got curious about this. I stumbled upon this puzzle in geeks for geeks (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/), and I thought if could this be possible/achieved using template metaprogramming? But I do not know what happens on the time complexity? Anyway as what @eran said it does not matter on compile time.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt I do not have an example code, I'm just curious about this because of my lack of understanding. My first thought is that the time complexities are evaluated on runtime so it will be O(1) since templates are evaluated on compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Suppose that I will be able to implement a template metaprogram that will "search for a duplicate element in an array or any container"

In order to do that with template metaprogramming, *the contents of the container would have to be known at compile time*.

There's no way to use template metaprogramming to shift the complexity burden off of run-time.

Comment: I understand, and since time complexities are relative to the input, I think it will not change the best case scenario even if evaluated on compile time. So technically, time complexity remains the same for the "search" and fibonacci.

Comment: Hmm.. how about the fibonacci. Since you will know the input to compute for the fibonacci sequence, does it's time complexity remain O(2 ^ N)?

Comment: You *don't* know the input until runtime, so the complexity is O(2**N) at runtime.  Assuming the recursive solution of fibonacci of course.

Comment: I meant the recursive solution for fibonacci. Thanks! I now understood.

Comment: Also note the implicit memoization of templates, which can affect (reduce) complexity. Fibonacci is a great example of this.

Comment: @QuestionC: Your post and comment are correct under the (reasonable) assumption that input is only provided *at runtime* -- but for cases like the recursive Fibonacci template code, I think it's reasonable to argue that "input" can be provided at compile time (e.g. in the form of compile-time constants).  In that case, assuming the compiler decides to inline everything, compile time will be O(2**N) and runtime will be O(1).